# How to pass an image resource by reference

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I have a class that inherits from a 3rd party ActiveX. The base class provides a call that is defined this way in C++;

```
HRESULT SetImage(VARIANT* theBuffer,
        LONG* theBufferSize
       );

Parameters
    theBuffer 
        The JPEG image data buffer.

    theBufferSize 
        Size of the image data buffer.
```

The jpg image I want to use (NoVideo.jpg) is a 'linked at compile time' resource (as in Resource.NoVideo)

I have tried things like this with no joy:

```
this.SetImage(ref Resources.NoVideo.GetHbitmap(), ref Resources.NoVideo.Size);
```

Can someone please show me the right way to make that call in C# using that resource image? The vendor is being sloooow and vague. They don't seem to know C# well enough to do more than guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540335/call-c-function-inside-c-sharp-via-function-pointer) post.