# Unmanaged Exports and delegates

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, delphi-7

I am using Robert Giesecke Unmanaged Exports to create a .NET wrapper DLL to use a .NET DLL in Delphi 7. Everything works fine so far, but now I have a function which needs to have a callback/delegate.

How can this be done?

Can I just give the function pointer to my .NET DLL and call it from there and when yes how is it done?

Comment: FWIW, if you are creating a wrapper to an existing .net DLL then mixed mode C++/CLI may be a better approach. It does at least rely on officially supported mechanisms rather than the magic that UnmanagedExports provides. Not that I have anything against UnmanagedExports for it is truly excellent.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'd love to use C++/CLI (I have a version that does) but it then requires the VC 2015 Redist, even though it's nothing but a thin passthrough wrapper.  Any way to remove that dependency or statically link it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You define a delegate type just as you would with a standard p/invoke.

Here's the simplest example that I can think of:

**C#**

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public delegate int FooDelegate();

    public class Class1
    {
        [DllExport()]
        public static int Test(FooDelegate foo)
        {
            return foo();
        }
    }
}
```

**Delphi**

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TFooDelegate = function: Integer; stdcall;

function Test(foo: TFooDelegate): Integer; stdcall; external 'ClassLibrary1.dll';

function Func: Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := 666;
end;

begin
  Writeln(Test(Func));
end.
```

**Output**

```
666
```

The default calling convention on the C# side is `CallingConvention.Stdcall` so I've gone along with that. That's the obvious thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It indeed much easier than what I used.

Answer (score -1):

You could:

1) Make the NET DLL function return an Integer, which is consumed by the Delphi 7 DLL. The varied return results will then trigger various procedures to be called inside the Delphi 7 DLL.

2) Make it fully native (Convert from NET to Delphi 7).

3) Make it fully NET (Make it fully NET instead).

4) If both of them are DLLs, you could export a native DLL function from Delphi to NET via an unmanaged DLL call.

Comment: This is indeed perfectly possible.

Comment: Why down-vote my answer for? I suggested answers. LOL. - the second person got -2...

Comment: Your answer deserves its downvote because it is factually incorrect, in a highly significant way. You state the impossibility of something that is in fact very possible.

Comment: That's better in that the erroneous statement has been removed. However, you don't address the crux of the question, which is how to pass a Delphi function pointer to a C# function, exported with Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports, and then call that Delphi function from the C# code. Instead you propose lots of alternatives. You might do that as a comment but you don't directly address the question that was asked.

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer, this [Call C function inside C# via function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540335/call-c-function-inside-c-sharp-via-function-pointer) helped me a lot

Basically you can just send the pointer and call it

On the C# side:

1. Define the Signature of the delegate

   ```
   public delegate void LinkCallback(int AValue);
   ```
2. Create a IntPtr Varialbe to store the pointer

   ```
   public IntPtr Callback;
   ```
3. In the DLL function which gets the pointer assign it to the variable

   ```
   Callback = new IntPtr(cb);
   ```
4. To call the callback you must marshal it

   ```
   LinkCallback callback = (LinkCallback)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ConList[Idx].Callback,typeof(LinkCallback));

   callback(10);
   ```

Comment: No need at all for `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`. This is much more complex than is needed.