# Why unsafe code context [related to pointer operation] is a security risk in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I needed to call C library function which takes pointers as argument from one C# program. In C# we need to guard the pointer operations with **#unsafe** keyword. [Microsoft C# documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/) says using pointers cause stability and security issues.

> In the common language runtime (CLR), unsafe code is referred to as
>   unverifiable code. Unsafe code in C# is not necessarily dangerous; it
>   is just code whose safety cannot be verified by the CLR. The CLR will
>   therefore only execute unsafe code if it is in a fully trusted
>   assembly. If you use unsafe code, it is your responsibility to ensure
>   that your code does not introduce security risks or pointer errors.

And the docs says

> Using unsafe code introduces security and stability risks.

I am new to C# language. I worked only in C language before and in UNIX environment. I understand an improper pointer have stability issues. It may crash the program/OS or may leads to unexpected results.

These are my questions:

1)I don't understand how pointer operations can lead to an security issue. The only thing I can think is invoking an function pointer which contains malicious code, but [this Stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540335/call-c-function-inside-c-sharp-via-function-pointer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) says that **unsafe context is not needed for invoking a function pointer** (please correct me if my understanding is wrong). Then How disabling pointer operations will increases the security?

2)We can call C functions from C# program, and those C functions may contains malicious code. Can CLR detect this security vulnerabilities?

Comment: *I don't understand how pointer operations can lead to an security issue.* <- are you serious? any buffer overflow, wrong arithmetics, use-after-free, and countless other subtle programming errors with pointers could be exploited.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks. Can please you change this commend to an answer with some link and explanations?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, more than the answer you already got, or else I'd probably have to write a book. The key issue with pointers is you can make all kinds of programming errors and there's no way to detect this at runtime --- so **if** a language wants to guard against that, it can't allow the use of pointers.

Comment: A security risk requires turning data into executable code.  Not a simple thing to do, it can only ever get started by memory corruption.  Not a simple thing to do, but a pointer is the ideal vehicle to get there.  It only knows an address and a type, it does not know what kind of object or data structure that address belongs to.  The CLR has a lot of countermeasures against such shenanigans, I don't know of any widespread malware attacks facilitated by unsafe C# code.  But the stability concern is a definitely a well-known issue.  ExecutionEngineException is very nasty to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example of security risks of the misuse of pointers is [use after free](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_freed_memory). One example of this issue is a [recently discovered security issue within Chrome](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2016-5213).

I'm not really familiar with C# but I guess that the CLR doesn't "understand" C code but rather execute it directly. Therefore I think that the CLR cannot analyze/detect issues with the C code you'd  like to use.